# How to fix "Closure: (dynamic) => void from Function '[function]': static." in Dart

Tags: function, dart, dynamic, static, closures

i tried to print a statement with function in dart. the code is written bellow :

```
void introduce(var a, var b, var c, var d){
  print("Nama saya $a, umur saya $b tahun, alamat saya di $c, dan saya punya hobby yaitu $d!");
}

void main(){
var name = "Agus";
var age = 30;
var address = "Jln. Malioboro, Yogyakarta";
var hobby = "Gaming";

introduce(name, age, address, hobby);
print(introduce); // Menampilkan "Nama saya Agus, umur saya 30 tahun, alamat saya di Jln. Malioboro, Yogyakarta, dan saya punya hobby yaitu Gaming!"
}
```

when i execute it, it shows the print, but it has "Closure: (dynamic, dynamic, dynamic, dynamic) => void from Function 'introduce': static" bellow the print.

```
Nama saya Agus, umur saya 30 tahun, alamat saya di Jln. Malioboro, Yogyakarta, dan saya punya hobby yaitu Gaming!
Closure: (dynamic, dynamic, dynamic, dynamic) => void from Function 'introduce': static.
```

is there any way that i can fix this? Thank you!

Comment: What exactly do you want to fix? It's what you programmed it to do. What did you expect  `print(introduce);` to do?

Comment: hi thanks for the feedback,

yes, it show the print, but it shows the syntax  "Closure: (dynamic, dynamic, dynamic, dynamic) => void from Function 'introduce': static." under the print(introduce) in my console, i wonder how to get rid of it.

Comment: Remove the `print(introduce);` line if you don't want to see it.

Comment: @nvoigt it works when i remove it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `print(introduce)`.

Functions in Dart are first-class citizens and when you do `print(introduce)` under the hood it's basically doing `print(introduce.toString())` so it will print out the function's runtime information. You're not calling that function... just printing out the function. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: thanks it works! i really new to dart and programming it self.